# Requesting rollback of this edit suggested by an anonymous user

Tags: discussion, editing

My question is regarding [this edit](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7508) that was suggested by an anonymous user on 6 April.

In my opinion, the paragraph that was added looks like a comment on the answer. With the edit, the answer doesn't make much sense: surely @Jasper isn't saying that they "did not write the answer below". Most likely the user who submitted the edit did not have an account on this SE and wanted to make a comment, and did so in the form of an edit.

So, since the edit detracts from the answer, I request that we rollback the post to the first version. Perhaps the submitted edit can be moved to a comment under the answer or under the question, should we feel the need to preserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Angst approved this, but I think you're right, it is clearly vandalism so I rolled back.